# Вопрос про получение всех записей, и после этого счётчик

Tags: count, php, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Есть такой запрос:

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT `id`, `type` FROM `tasks_done` WHERE `uid` = 1");

$likes_count = 0;
while($d = $db->fetch($q)) {
 $type = $d['type'];

 if($type == 1) $likes_count++;
}
```

Плохо ли это? Не будет тормозить браузер, если слишком много записей например?

Или же проще делать так?

```
$likes_count = $db->num($db->query("SELECT `id`, `type` FROM `tasks_done` WHERE `uid` = 1 AND `type` = 1"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше так:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM `tasks_done` WHERE `uid` = 1 AND `type` = 1;
```

P.S.:

> Плохо ли это?

Конечно плохо!

> Не будет тормозить браузер, если слишком много записей например?

Код PHP выполняется на сервере, а не в браузере.

UPD:
Тем что под этот огромный массив с данными на сервере выделяется память и потом вы начинаете тупо перебирать записи и считать количество каждого типа...
Для этих целей есть оператор GROUP BY в SQL. Если вам надо посчитать количество записей каждого типа для пользователей, то используте следующий запрос:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) cnt, type FROM tasks_done WHERE uid = 1 GROUP BY type;
```

Comment: @ua6xh, а чем плохо? Например у меня несколько типов. А тут я получаю всё одним запросом.

Comment: 1. SQL запрос с группировкой (или без нее, неважно) выполнится в любом случае быстрее полного перебора. Можете проверить, например, на миллионе записей - увидите сами, разница существенна.
2. Если есть возможность, лучше выборку и группировку данных поручать СУБД - она для этих целей и заточена.